# How to handle delete message on Thunderbird

Tags: javascript, add-on, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I have a Thunderbird add-on and should to fix some bugs.

I need to handle deleting messages and do some actions, but I don't get any information about `onDeleteEvent`.

I only found [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Events) and tried to use

```
document.addEventListener("onMessagesRemoved", function() {
  Application.console.log('deleted');
});
```

But nothing happens.

How I can handle delete messages event?

Answer (score 0):

The notification is fired on listeners of nsIMsgFolders. So you need folder.addEventListener, not document.addEventListener. You have to provide a listener for each specific folder that you want to watch deletion for.

(reference: http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mailnews/base/public/nsIMsgFolder.idl#652)